# What was the end of line convention for text files on the 8-bit Commodores

Tags: commodore-64, commodore-pet, file-format, vic-20, commodore-128

A two part question:

1. Did an agreed upon convention for end of line (EOL) within text files exist on the 8-bit Commodores?
2. If there was a convention, what was it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C64 Basic used a CR as EOL for disk files.

(source: [Commodore SX-64 User's Guide](https://archive.org/details/Commodore_SX-64_Users_Guide_1983_Commodore), page 22: “*CR stands for the CHR$ code 13, the carriage return, which is automatically PRINTed at the end of ever PRINT or PRINT# statement* …
”, and verified by hex dump of disk image showing 0x0d at line end.)

Comment: It seemed like ASCII 13 was the EOL for all the 8-bits I used back in the day. Exception was UNIX platforms (LF) and IBM PC (CR/LF). I'm not aware of any other variations.

Comment: Amstrad CPC had CR/LF, as I suspect had CP/M

Comment: @bjb: For files, CR was definitely the norm.  For printers, the combination of CR+LF was very common, since it allowed use of a lone CR for overprinting (a convention observed in some Unix utilities).  It's interesting to note that early ASCII-based teletypes required that some time elapse between the receipt of a CR and the receipt of the next printable character, so if a CR *wasn't* followed by an LF it would have to be followed by a NUL, BEL, or other non-printing character absent some other means of ensuring a delay.

Comment: MSX also used CR/LF, so it was mainstream

Answer (score 3):

I remember downloading a lot of dox files off BBS's back in the day, and given that most files were ascii from other platforms, I think the standard CrLf or Cr or Lf end of line was common.  But I also remember word processors like Bank Street Writer and Speedscript being proprietary file formats.

So it was probably dealers choice; no official standard, and it was up to the operator to pair the data files with appropriate software capable of properly viewing them.

I also remember moving data from speedscript via null modem to apple so I could print on the ImageWriter at school used to give me no end of trouble...  grr...  :-)